# Fundamental group of 2-torus minus a single point

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

So, if I take one torus and take off one single point, what will be its fundamental group? I think that one single point will not change the topology in this sense. Or will it? If so, how?

Comment: In fact, if I think well it will be like an eight, right?
Then, the correct value of the fundamental group for this figure is $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$, is this?

Comment: removing a point will often change the topology drastically.  For example, $\Bbb R^2$ minus a point gives you $\Bbb Z$

Comment: yes, yes, in fact....

Comment: It's easiest to think about the fundamental domain of a square, remove the center of the square, and then retract the remainder onto the boundary.  Then, perform the typical identifications of the boundary and you should get a figure 8.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Michael Burr.

Comment: The reason that the fundamental group changes is that the fundamental group measures how to "go around" holes in the object.  When you remove a point, you have a new hole to "go around"

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/22980/10014) (I'm hesitant to say "duplicate")

Comment: @Leonardo Just for extra information: If the dimension of the manifold is greater or equal to $3$, then removing a point does not change the fundamental group. You can use Seifert-Van Kampen to prove that, but I guess this is done somewhere in Lee's Topological Manifolds book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we remove a point the topology will change and the fundamental group will change drastically! The fundamental group of the torus is 
$$
\pi_1(T)=Z\oplus Z
$$
but if you remove a point the fundamental will be even a non abelian group:
$$
\pi_1(T-\{p\})= F(\alpha, \beta)
$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the two cycles of the figure 8, and $F(\alpha, \beta)$ is the free group generated by $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

All theses problems appear because of the existence of the so called "Peano curves" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve (which are really complicated curves that are surjective). 
For example following this naive idea that removing a point does not change the topology we could end up with the following WRONG proof for the sphere:

1-"We remove a point to $S^2$ and does not change anything", then $S^2-{p} \simeq R^2$, but $R^2$ is contractible and we get $\pi_1(S^2) = \pi_1(S^2-{p}) = \pi_1(R^2)=0$.

Although the achieved result is true, we have to be careful because this proof is COMPLETELY WRONG! And the reason is the subtle idea that there exist paths filling $S^2$ which clearly will not have a homotopy equivalence class in $\pi_1(S^2-{p})$.

Comment: It's not clear at all why you think the existence of space filling curves is what's leads to a change in the fundamental group...

Comment: You are right. Certainly is not a proof, but gives you a pretty simple idea why it should not work. I am not saying is the REASON that changes the fundamental group, it is just a counter example curve that does not fit in the fundamental curve of the space minus a point.

Comment: I don't believe your comment about space filling curves is correct: a consequence of the simplicial approximation theorem is that every path is homotopic to a non-space fillling path, so you can fix the wrong proof that $S^2$ is simply connected this way. The reason this doesn't work for $T$ isn't due to the existence of space filling curves, but rather you can't make the same conclusion since $\pi_1(T-\{p\})$ is non-trivial.